# 'int' object is not iterable - Keras

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, keras

Hace unas semanas empecé a interesarme por el tema de las acciones, y decidí desarrollar un código en Python que predijera el precio de una acción al cierre del mercado.

Pero después de unos días intentando resolver el problema, no hay manera.

Traceback:

```
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:805 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:795 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1259 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2730 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3417 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:788 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:754 train_step
    y_pred = self(x, training=True)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1012 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\sequential.py:375 call
    return super(Sequential, self).call(inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py:425 call
    inputs, training=training, mask=mask)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\functional.py:560 _run_internal_graph
    outputs = node.layer(*args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\base_layer.py:1012 __call__
    outputs = call_fn(inputs, *args, **kwargs)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py:231 call
    lambda: array_ops.identity(inputs))
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\utils\control_flow_util.py:115 smart_cond
    pred, true_fn=true_fn, false_fn=false_fn, name=name)
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\smart_cond.py:54 smart_cond
    return true_fn()
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py:226 dropped_inputs
    noise_shape=self._get_noise_shape(inputs),
C:\Users\msi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\layers\core.py:215 _get_noise_shape
    for i, value in enumerate(self.noise_shape):

TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

`input = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 25, batch_size =32)`

Creo que lo que falla es el model.fit , aunque no entiendo el por qué.

Código entero:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web
import datetime as dt

from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM

# Company and Dates
company = "FB"
start = dt.datetime(2017,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2021,1,1)

data = web.DataReader(company, "yahoo", start, end)

# Data

scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
scaled_data = scaler.fit_transform(data["Close"].values.reshape(-1, 1))

prediction_days = 30

x_train = []
y_train = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(scaled_data)):
    x_train.append(scaled_data[x - prediction_days:x,0])
    y_train.append(scaled_data[x,0])


x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)

x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))

# Neural

model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],1)))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(LSTM(units=50))
model.add(Dropout(0,2))
model.add(Dense(units = 1)) # Prediction of the new day (closed value)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")
inputmodel = model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs = 25, batch_size =32)

# Test Neural Netowk Accuracy

testStart = dt.datetime(2021,1,1)
testEND = dt.datetime.now()

test_data = web.DataReader(company, "yahoo", testStart, testEND)
actual_price = test_data["Close"].values
total_dataset = pd.concat((data,["Close"], test_data["Close"]), axis=0)

model_input = total_dataset[len(total_dataset) - len(test_data) - prediction_days:].values
model_input = model_input.reshape(-1,1)
model_input = scaler.transform(model_input)


# Predictions

x_test = []

for x in range(prediction_days, len(model_input)):
    x_test.append(model_input[x - prediction_days:x, 0])

x_test = np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1],1))

predicted_prices = model.predict(x_test)
predicted_prices = scaler.inverse_transform(predicted_prices)

# Plot Predictions
plt.plot(actual_price, color = "yellow")
plt.plot(predicted_prices, color = "green")
plt.title(f"{company} share price")
plt.xlabel("Time")
plt.ylabel(f"{company} share price")
plt.legend()
plt.show()

#Predictions

real_data = [model_input[len(model_input)+ 1 - prediction_days:len(model_input+1), 0]]
real_data = np.array(real_data)
real_data = np.reshape(real_data, (real_data.shape[0], real_data.shape[1],1))

pred = model.predict(real_data)

pred = scaler.inverse_transform(pred)
```

EDIT: He publicado todo el código.

El Traceback es demasiado largo como para ponerlo todo entero.

Comment: ¿Qué son x_train, y_train?

Comment: @CandidMoe Son las variables dónde guardo los floats que luego los meto en arrays.

Comment: Hola Pau! Por favor puedes añadir el código, aquí solo está la traza de error (que no está completa), es difícil solucionar un código sin poder verlo. Agrega por favor tu código y la traza completa de error. El error te dice que estás intentando iterar por un entero, para iterar necesitas un interable, como una lista, tupla, etc.

Comment: @RubialesAlberto Listo! Y perdón, el traceback es muy largo, por lo cuál pensé que lo vital era el int not interable, ya está todo!

Comment: Muchas gracias, si no quieres poner el traceback entero por ser demasiado largo, por favor busca el parrafo en el traceback que te indica la linea de tu código que lo produce y adjuntalo, esto es lo más importante.

Answer (score 0):

El problema esta exactamente aqui:

```
Dropout(0,2)
```

En python, para escribir numeros en punto flotante, se usa el punto, no la coma, entonces esta linea deberia ser escrita asi:

```
Dropout(0.2)
```

Si usas la coma para representar numeros, esto se interpreta como dos diferentes parametros para la clase Dropout y produce el problema que mencionas.